# How to reset password on Rails 5 API mode

Tags: api, authentication, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5 applications created with `--api` option don't expect html content. What are the alternatives to allow users to reset their password without an html form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this flow:

1. User presses reset password button client-side
2. Server-side a new random password is set and sent by email
3. User logs in with random password and resets password client-side

Do you have another solution?

Comment: Nice, that gives me an idea. I think it gets even better if the email contains a link to the client-side app that will auto-log-in the user with the generated password or reset-token. I've seen this for a few apps. Can be done in mobile too.

iOS: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2301787 
Android: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html